# Как плавно заполнить background у div-а?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, css-animation

Есть блок, который на странице выглядит так:

[image: Блок, background которого нужно заполнить]

Html выглядит так:

```
<div class="relative rounded-full rating_border overflow-hidden h-9 bg-grey-100 mb-3">
<div class="bg-primary absolute inset-0 text-white z-10 whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden text-lg flex items-center transition-all" style="width: 90%; transition-duration: 300ms; transition-delay: 0ms;">
<span class="pl-3 absolute px-3 py-1 inset-0">Value - <span>90</span>%</span>
</div>
<span class="text-primary text-lg absolute px-3 py-1 inset-0">Value - <span>90</span>%</span>
</div>
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы при прокрутке страницы, когда блок попадал в видимую часть экрана, div за указанное время заполнялся бы на указанное значение, в данном случае на 90%.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Можно использовать JS.

И второй вопрос, подскажите каким плагином делается, чтобы когда элемент попадал в видимую часть экрана числа автоматически прокручивались от 0 до 90

Comment: Ну смотрите, если вы хотите плавное заполнение слева на право, тогда у вас вся CSS структура неправильна, т.к. тут нужно работать с `background-image` и `background-position` (И другими по типу `...-repeat`, `...-size` и т.п.), можно конечно сделать отдельный задний фон и вертеть его с помощью `left`, но такой подход неправильный.

Comment: можно просто добавить анимацию, где будет меняться градиент с полностью белого на фиолетовый с белым 90\10 и вешать на какое то событие в js, только какое не ясно...